# How to pass passwords to spark on EMR

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, pyspark, emr, amazon-emr

Say your spark cluster which runs on Amazon EMR needs to access a postgresql database. What is the best way to give it it's login and password?
Those are some ways we have tried:

- Have configuration file on S3 with info (not ideal since password is in plain text on S3)
- Pass it as environment variable as a part of spark-env on EMR settings (does not work since executors do not have access to environment variables. It can be set in spark config with spark.executorEnv.[EnvironmentVariableName], but this would require again the password to be in plain text in the spark config file which would also have to be in S3).

Is there a better way I am missing?

Answer (score 1):

you could use EC2 instance metadata to push up the secret to each ec2 instance, use GET calls to retrieve it. Ideally, create a login/password only valid for the lifespan of the EMR cluster, deleting it (or at least, reset the password) after it's been torn down.

AFAIK there's no explicit support for this in Spark, but if you get the AWS SDK on the classpath, you can use EC2MetadataUtils to work with it

Comment: Is there documentation on how to push EC2 instance metadata? I couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 0):

> Pass it as environment variable as a part of spark-env on EMR settings
>   (does not work since executors do not have access to environment
>   variables.

If you are able to extract the variable in the driver, you may "transmit" it to the executors by setting it to to a broadcast variable. If you are setting up some kind of DB client in each executor, they will have access to the value so long as it is broadcast.

https://blog.knoldus.com/broadcast-variables-in-spark-how-and-when-to-use-them/

Answer (score 0):

First you encrypt the password with KMS. Then you have numerous options to pass the encrypted value to your driver or worker. Inside driver and worker you can use KMS to decrypt the password.

To pass the encrypted value you can

- pass it as argument to spark-submit, or
- pass it via EMR classification (spark-env for driver, yarn-env for udfs on workers), or
- pass it as argument to a bootstrap action and add it there to something like bashrc (I don't recommend it).